# JPanels not being added to the JFrame

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jframe, jpanel

So I was building this very simple game and I've add all the elements (for the movement) but when I hit run it only shows me the `JFrame` and not the `JPanel`. I should mention that I am very new to Java and the code you see bellow might not be the cleanest (it's also not complete).

**Main**

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
       GameFrame frame = new GameFrame();
    }
}
```

**GameFrame**

```
public class GameFrame extends  JFrame {
         GamePanel panel;
     GameFrame() {
         panel = new GamePanel();
         this.add(panel);
         this.setTitle("Survival");
         this.setResizable(false);
         this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
         this.pack();
         this.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
         this.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

**Panel**

```
public class GamePanel extends JPanel implements Runnable {
    static final int GAME_WIDTH = 1000;
    static final int GAME_HEIGHT = GAME_WIDTH * 9 / 16;
    static final Dimension SCREEN_SIZE = new Dimension(GAME_WIDTH, GAME_HEIGHT);
    static final int PLAYER_WIDTH = 40;
    static final int PLAYER_HEIGHT = 40;
    Thread gameThread;
    Graphics graphics;
    Player player;
    int fireBallY = (int) (Math.random() * 563);
    Fireballs fireball;
    Image image;
    int dimSky = 150;

     GamePanel() {
         newFireballs();
         newPlayer();
         this.setFocusable(true);
         this.addKeyListener(new actionListener());
         this.setPreferredSize(SCREEN_SIZE);
         this.setBackground(Color.CYAN);
         gameThread = new Thread(this);
         gameThread.start();
    }

    private void newPlayer() {
        player = new Player(200, 150, PLAYER_WIDTH, PLAYER_HEIGHT);
    }
    private void newFireballs() {
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) new Fireballs(800, fireBallY, PLAYER_WIDTH, PLAYER_HEIGHT);
    }

    public void paint(Graphics g) {
        image = createImage(getWidth(), getHeight());
        graphics = image.getGraphics();
        draw(graphics);
        g.drawImage(image, 0,0, this);
    }

    public void draw(Graphics g) {
        player.draw(g);
    }

    public void move() {
         player.moveX();
         player.moveY();
    }

    public void collision() {}

    public void run() {
        //game loop
        long lastTime = System.nanoTime();
        double amountOfTicks =  60.0;
        double ns = 1000000000 / amountOfTicks;
        double delta = 0;
        while (true) {
            long now = System.nanoTime();
            delta += (now - lastTime) / ns;
            lastTime = now;
            if (delta >= 1) {
                move();
                collision();
                repaint();
                delta--;
                System.out.println("It Works!");
            }
        }
    }

    private class actionListener extends KeyAdapter {
        public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
            player.KeyPressed(e);
        }
        public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
            player.KeyReleased(e);
        }
    }
}
```

**Player**

```
public class Player extends Rectangle {
int xVelocity;
int yVelocity;
int speed = 10;

    public Player(int x, int y, int PLAYER_WIDTH, int PLAYER_HEIGHT) {
        super(x,y, PLAYER_WIDTH, PLAYER_HEIGHT);
    }

    public void KeyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
        if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_W) {
            setYDirection(-speed);
            moveX();
            moveY();
        }
        if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_S) {
            setYDirection(+speed);
            moveX();
            moveY();
        }
        if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_D) {
            setXDirection(+speed);
            moveX();
            moveY();
        }
        if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_A) {
            setXDirection(-speed);
            moveX();
            moveY();
        }
    }
    public void KeyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
        if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_W) {
            setYDirection(-10);
            moveX();
            moveY();
        }
        if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_S) {
            setYDirection(+1);
            moveX();
            moveY();
        }
        if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_D) {
            setXDirection(+1);
            moveX();
            moveY();
        }
        if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_A) {
            setXDirection(-1);
            moveX();
            moveY();
        }
    }

    public void setXDirection(int xVelocity) {
        x = x + xVelocity;
    }
    public void setYDirection(int yVelocity) {
        y = y + yVelocity;
    }
    public void moveX() {
        x = x + xVelocity;
    }
    public void moveY() {
        y = y + yVelocity;
    }
    public void draw(Graphics g) {
        g.setColor(Color.RED);
        g.fillRect(x, y, width, height);
        }
}
```

There are other classes but those are completely empty and I don't think they are the cause of my problem.

Comment: `Frame frame = new Frame();` is Frame your own class? if so, please provide the relevant bits. Is it an `java.awt.Frame`? if so, you never add your Panel to it.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. 1) What is `Frame`, 2) Don't use `java.util.Thread` for doing something in the background, instead use a `Swing-Timer` or a `SwingWorker`. Don't name your classes as `Frame`, `Panel`, etc, they might confuse you or us into thinking about `java.awt.Frame` or `java.awt.Panel` which is a deprecated technology. 3) Painting should be done by overriding `paintComponent(...)` not `paint(...)` and don't cut the paint-chain (don't remove `super.paintComponent(...)` call.

Comment: 4) `while(true)` is a really bad thing to do in a Swing proram. See point (2) again. 5) For better help sooner post a proper [mre] that demonstrates your issue. But before take the [tour], read [ask] and then come back and [edit] your question to include the MRE well formatted and not as you posted it this time. A program that isolates the issue, should be of no more than 50 lines for your particular case.

Comment: 1) Don't call your classs "Frame" and "Panel". There are AWT classes with those names already so it is very confusing. A class name should be more descriptive. 2) You didn't post the "Frame" code, so we don't see where you actually add the panels to the class. 3) Custom painting is done by overriding `paintComponent()` and you invoke super.paintComponent(...) as the first statement.

Comment: 4) Walk before you run. First you create the "Frame" and then test. Then you create the "Panel" and add it to the frame and then test. Why are you trying to write all the game logic before even being able to display the panel??? So post a proper [mre] demonstrating the problem. That is code that we can copy/paste/compile/test that just display the frame and the panel. All the other code is irrelevant to the stated question.

Comment: Sorry for being an idiot, I forgot to show you guys the GameFrame class. Oh and I have now renamed my Frame and Panel class to GameFrame and GamePanel.

Comment: Yet you haven't created a [mre] that was asked twice 2 hours ago. This is too much code for us to check, and 80% of it is wrong, so if something is wrong in your code, create a brand new program that isolates your issue, following the above tips.

Comment: Start with the basic working example from the Swing tutorial on [Custom Painting](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/refining.html). Then modify that working code one step at a time to add different functionality. So the first step is to just display the panel will simple painting.

Comment: Ok, what if I have a problem and can't figure out what is causing the problem in the first place? The code I'm using is based on a pong tutorial which I had written and it had worked so naturally I tried to modify to make my own game. Frakcool I appreciate you trying to help me but for some reason you're being incredibly rude about it. Anyways I think there have been plenty of other useful tips that I am planning on following so to everyone in this thread, thanks.  (I should mention that I do know the problem now, just incase this comment confused you)

Answer (score -1):

Several issues:

1. If you are new to Swing, do not start off with too much complexity.
   when you cannot see a JPanel on screen, my approach would be first to amend that. Only then add some complexity to the JPanel itself.
   I have done that below by simply displaying a big red JPanel.
2. Is the reason you do not see anything because you did not set a `JFrame.size(Dimension d)`? I have added that in the construtor of the JFrame
3. Indeed, as @Frakcool and @camickr have pointed out in their comments, the canonic approach in Swing is overriding `JPanel.paintComponent(Graphics g)`
4. You should obey the thread landscape that Swing has prepared for you. That is indeed use `SwingWorker` threads for background tasks as @Frakcool commented.
   And also use the `EventDispatchingThread` to handle events and startup. In the main method below, you see the call to `SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable())`.
   The more complex your application gets, the more likely you will run into trouble if not obeying the `EventDispatchingThread`.

here is my - minimal - sample code containing examples for the points above. Within your game logic may be further work to be done, which I think is out of scope.

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class GameFrame extends JFrame {
    GamePanel panel;

    GameFrame() {
        panel = new GamePanel();
        this.add(panel);
        this.setTitle("Survival");
        this.pack();

        /*
         * might help to set a window size:
         */
        setSize(800, 600);

        this.setResizable(false);
        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        
        this.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        this.setVisible(true);
    }

    private class GamePanel extends JPanel {
        @Override
        protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            // check if needed, eg for subcomponents
            // super.paintComponent(g);
            g.setColor(Color.red);
            g.fillRect(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight());

        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                new GameFrame();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: (1-) 1) You should not set the size of the frame. Each component should determine its own preferred size and then the pack() method will work properly. Read the custom painting tutorial. The link was given in the comments. 2) as was stated twice above, you should invoke super.paintComponent(). Don't do the custom painting yourself. Don't reinvent the wheel. Use the setBackground() method to change the background color. In the simple example there is no reason to even extend paintComponent(). 3) setResizable(false) should be invoked before the pack(). 4) you should not extend JFrame.